# prometheus alert manager how to ungroup alerts

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I need to ungroup the alerts send through prometheus/alertmanager to an email. If I had understood well it is against the philosophy of alertmanager to ungroup alerts, but I need it, is there anyway to do it based on the timestamp or something else ???

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "group_by" option to set how alerts will be grouped, and you can disable aggregation entirely, passing through all alerts as-is with:

```
group_by: ['...']
```

See the Alertmanager documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route).

Comment: In my case for jenkins metrics a good solution for jenkins jobs was `group_by: ['jenkins_job'] `. Thank you for the answer.